# convert one array object to IEnumerable

Tags: arrays, vb.net, list, except

I want to compare two datagridviews, and use the `Except` method on the `IEnumerable` interface, in order to know the difference among them.
One example of my datagridviews:

```
DG1

idProduct     Item 

1             Item A
1             Item B
2             Item C
2             Item D

DG2
idProduct Item    Price IdSupplier
1         Item A  10.00 1
1         Item B  20.00 1
2         Item C  30.00 1
2         Item D  40.00 1
1         Item A  20.00 3
1         Item B  30.00 3
2         Item C  40.00 3
2         Item D  50.00 3
```

So, I have tried to put the data from `dgv1` into an array, and the data from `dgv2` into an dynamic array, cause I want a list for each `IdSupplier` (in case, 1, 3) and compare them with the except method. My code is:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data
Imports datagridviewTota.DataSet1TableAdapters
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Collections.ArrayList
Imports System.Collections.CollectionBase

Public Class form1

Public itemArray()
Public ItemListArray()
Public Shared j As Integer

Private sub main ()

   (…)
   Dim ds1 As New DataSet
   Dim item As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
   Dim Id As Integer
   Dim dr As DataRow
   Dim dr1 As DataRow
   Dim itemList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
   Dim idSuppliers () as integer
   ReDim itemArray(j) ‘ j represents the numbers of elements in idSuppliers() (third column of dg2)

 Try
    //create an array for the dgv1//
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv1.Rows                  
       item = dgv1.Rows(row.Index).Cells(1).Value
       itemList.Add(item)                                
    Next

    Dim itemListArray = itemList.toArray()

    //create a dynamic array for the dgv2 by filtering for each idSuppliers, put the values from the second column into a list and convert each list into a dynamic array//

    For Each element In idSuppliers
       Dim dv As New DataView()
       dv = New DataView(ds1.Tables("idProduct"))
            With dv
                .RowFilter = "idSupplier = " & element & " "
            End With
       dgv2.DataSource = dv

       For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv2.Rows                 
          Id = dgv2.Rows(row.Index).Cells(3).Value

          If Id = element Then
             item = dgv2.Rows(row.Index).Cells(1).Value
             itemList.Add(item)                         
          End If                            
       Next

       itemArray(i) = itemList.ToArray()
       itemList.clear()

       i = i + 1     
    Next
end sub
```

So, I have tried the `IEnumerable.Except`, but it seems that my `itemArray()` is a object, cause I got the message `"System.linq.Enumerable+<ExceptIterator>d_99'1[System.Object]"`, when I try to try to cast `exceptItems`, as follows:

```
Dim exceptItems = itemListArray.Except(itemArray(2))
```

I also have tried:

```
Dim onlyInFirstSet As IEnumerable(Of String) = itemListArray.Except(itemArray(2))

            Dim output As New System.Text.StringBuilder
            For Each str As String In onlyInFirstSet
               output.AppendLine(str)
            Next
            MsgBox(output.ToString())
```

And know I get the err. number 13. I think the problem is that I have to convert `itemArray()` into an `IEnumerable`, is there any way that I could do this without major changes in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have `option strict`, the compiler doesn't know what type your `itemArray()` is so it uses the lowest common denominator of object.

You should turn option strict on and then fix the errors. You can do it either in the project properties or at the top of the class using `Options Strict`. Not using strict is a hold over from vb6 days and really helps to avoid problems like this. It will force you to define your variables as what they should be.

Comment: Holly god! thanks! I turned this thing on, and saw a lot of work...I will turn it off again...

Answer (score 1):

`Except` is only on the `IEnumerable(Of T)` interface, not on the vanilla `IEnumerable`.

`IEnumerable(Of T)` is implemented on a plain array, so you don't have to double-load your data.

Also, since `Except` is an extension method, you need to import `System.Linq`.

Comment: Hi, thanks! So, is there a way to convert system.string objects to system.IEnumerable(of T)?

Comment: Well, a string is IEnumerable(of Char)...   But that doesn't seem to be what you need...

Comment: Hello thanks! I see that if I implement the IEnumerable I will get an IEnumerable (of Char). To prevent this, I perhaps should use a list or Arraylist, and avoid the .toarray method? That's ok! As there's no problem to use this for my dgv1 list values, how could I use them to store the values from my dgv2?

Thanks!